# Remove default headers with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, restangular

I'm wondering why everybody asking about 'setting default headers' in Restangular for authorization, but there's no info how to clear this header if user do 'log out'.

I do:

```
Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({Authorization: accessToken});
```

How to manually remove this header?

Answer (score 2):

```
Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({})
```

This will do the trick

Comment: this will clean every custom headers, but not only 'Authorization' ;)

Answer (score 0):

In documentation there isn't information about it. But you can get default headers via Restangular.defaultHeaders properly. So i suppose that you can reset or remove header from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addRequestInterceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addrequestinterceptor) to set Authorization to `null` before each request if no valid token is available like :

```
Restangular.addRequestInterceptor(

  function(element, operation, what, url) {

    var accessToken = user.isLoggedIn() ? user.access_token : null;

    Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': accessToken});

    return element;

});
```

Or you can use [addfullrequestinterceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addfullrequestinterceptor) to apply any logic you need to your headers before sending any of them.